# How to pass a function or expression as an argument?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a complete function, that takes in an expression:

```
def graph(formula):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

    X = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.5)
    X = X[X != 0]
    Y = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.5)
    Y = Y[Y != 0]
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

    Z=[[0],[0]]
    expression = "Z=" + formula
    exec(expression)
```

Now I want to do `graph("X+Y")`, and then it should do Z = X + Y. It doesn't do that. I have tried doing the same with `eval` instead of `exec`, but no luck.

Comment: Are you looking for a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to pass a "formula" that computes `Z` from `X` and `Y`. Rather than using `exec` or `eval` and running into issues with namespaces, a better way to do that is to pass in a function. As user [s3cur3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417451/s3cur3) commented, an easy way to do that is with a `lambda` expression:

```
def graph(func):
    # set up X and Y up here

    Z = func(X, Y)

    # do stuff with Z after computing it?

graph(lambda X, Y: X+Y)
```

If you need more complicated logic that you can fit in a lambda, you can write out a full function if you need to:

```
def my_func(x, y):  # this could be done in a lambda too, but lets pretend it couldn't
    if random.random() < 0.5: 
        return x + y
    return x - y

graph(my_func)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for! It would be great if I could get rid of the first part somehow and only have X+Y, but this does the job too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean to pass to your function like so (to calculate Z),

```
def graph(formula)
    ...
graph(X+Y)
...
```

If so, why not just pass to separate values (or arrays of values)? Such as,

```
def graph(x, y):
    ...
graph(4, 5)
...
```

or,

```
mypoints = [[1, 3], [4, 8], [8, 1], [10, 3]] # 2-D array
def graph(XY):
    for point in XY:
        x = point[0]
        y = point[1]
.... # everything else

graph(mypoints )
...
```

For a full example of this, check out [Method: Stats.linregress( )](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/data-science-with-python-8-ways-to-do-linear-regression-and-measure-their-speed-b5577d75f8b) in this article (scroll down a bit).

Otherwise, you could:

- pass the data as an array (a **table** of X, Y values if you will).
- if it is a super complex formula that will have a bunch of attributes and methods attached to it (such as including complex numbers), perhaps creating a `Formula class`.

You could also write a function using the lambda syntax. This would give you the freedom of having an object (like I suggested above) as well as a "function" (of course they are practically synonymous). Read [more](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) in the docs.

Comment: The issue is that in this case, I will make a 3d graph. So Z = X+Y will create an array containing many Z values, so passing just 4 and 5 isn't an option.  Passing a table of Z would work, however I want to find a way where I can do my graph with just one expression.

Comment: @DunkeyKing Are you passing Z as well? I could not tell from your snippet. Which is why it is both more readable and memorable to you to pass the data individually as parameters. So, then I would create a graph(X, Y, Z) function in your case.

Comment: Hm I guess I could also declare X and Y globally and only pass Z! Thanks

Comment: @DunkeyKing You could declare these values globally, but I would advise against. It would be way to easy to forget and accidently  (X, Y & Z are common variable names in a pinch!) and assign something else to these!

Comment: I'm really confused by this answer, and why it's accepted. It doesn't seem to be addressing the question at all. In the question, the `graph` function is providing the `X` and `Y` values, but you seem to be suggesting that the caller should provide them. That seems backwards. The caller is supposed to be providing some means to compute `Z` from `X` and `Y`.

Comment: @Blckknght I assume the often more viable, that you wish to calculate Z and you will be providing X and Y as they are _variable_. Z is often what you want and the **dependent variable**, why would you ever pass the dependent variable to your function? I would consider this bad practice in fact.

Comment: @theQuantumMechanic I wish to pass the way to calculate Z. X and Y are arrays of 200 from -50 to 50 (in 0.5 steps, soo, and in the end I will be an array of 200 arrays of 200 values.

Comment: @DunkeyKing added an example with a 2D array with your last comment in mind. This is how I would pass the data to my function.